# mysql start and stop error

Tags: mysql

I install a mysql 4.1(Ok it's very old version) on debian.
the service start and stop correctly but show this error.

```
    root@VM03:~# /etc/init.d/mysql start
/etc/init.d/mysql: 63: /etc/init.d/mysql: source: not found
Starting MySQL
/etc/init.d/mysql: 117: /etc/init.d/mysql: log_success_msg: not found
```

and this

```
root@VM03:~# /etc/init.d/mysql stop
/etc/init.d/mysql: 63: /etc/init.d/mysql: source: not found
Shutting down MySQL
../etc/init.d/mysql: 117: /etc/init.d/mysql: log_success_msg: not found
```

i use the mysql.server default.

Someone to help.
Best,
JGois

Answer (score 1):

These are clearly bugs in particular 4.1 version , refer these bug reports:

http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=24294

http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=9852